# How to stick footer to bottom (not fixed) even with scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want the footer of this page to stick to the bottom, below all content, but not fixed in the screen. The problem is that when the body has more than 100% of height, the footer stay in the middle of the screen, and not in the bottom.

I've seen a lot of tutorials on how to achieve this, using "position: absolute" + "bottom: 0" and stuff, but everything failed.

Check it out:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Open+Sans|Ubuntu+Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Matheus's Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="title-div">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h3>Home</h3>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Articles</h3>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Perfil</h3>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>Settings</h3>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
      <p>Texto teste Texto teste Texto teste Texto teste Texto teste Texto teste Texto teste Texto teste Texto teste Texto teste </p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>
    <div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  float: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8%;
  background-color: #424242;
  color: #FFD740;
}

.title-div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto 5%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  border-right: solid 2px #FFD740;
}

header nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  left: 15%;
}

header ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto 2% auto 0;
}

#body {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 8%;
  padding-bottom: 15%; /* Height of the footer */
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #FFD740;
  background-color: #424242;
  clear: both;
}
```

Link to printscreen of the result:

[image: link to printscreen of the result]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think this might help you.

Just showing you the way how to achieve what you want.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#header {
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 10px;
}
#content {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
  background: #ffab62;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <!-- #header -->

  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <!-- #content -->

  <div id="footer">
  </div>
  <!-- #footer -->

</div>
<!-- #wrapper -->
```

> Make sure the value for 'padding-bottom' on #content is equal to or greater than the height of #footer.

**Update:**

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/523euaph/1/) to play around.

Comment: I saw this code before but couldn't figure out what was missing, the problem was my "#body" didn't have the "position: relative".

Comment: Everything looks fine now! I just have to adjust some widths and heights, thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Comment: This answer was good at the time, but the flexbox answer should be preferred now, since is avoids absolute positioning, now that it is fully supported by all major browsers.

Answer (score 61):

The accepted answer might be a bit outdated since we have Flexbox now. Give the container a `min-height: 100vh` and the footer a `margin-top: auto` so you don't have to deal with absolute positioning and fixed heights.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
}

.content {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree that flexbox is a better/easier way of doing it. But instead of using margin-top: auto; on the footer I would add flew-grow: 1; on the content.

Comment: +1 for @Gudradain's comment - the site I was working on already used margin-top for the footer. flex-grow: 1 saved a whole lot of work.

Comment: You're a genius !!! easy way to fix the footer to bottom :) And you don't need to embed header content and footer in a container div, you can simply remove the container div and set flex-column to the body :)

Comment: `flex-grow: 1;` - had a typo. but it's perfect  ! thanks a lot

Comment: frustratingly, this does not work as expected with Safari on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and this worked for me [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc2olxLgKLk).

I did this way in the CSS file (base.css):

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

footer{
    padding: 3em;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

And I've linked the css file in the html (base.html):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'<path to css>'"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The explanation is at the link that I've put on the answer. I've followed the video and described the solution that worked for me.

Comment: @IasminiGomes All links eventually expire. When your link expires, users will have no context to determine whether your answer is pertinent.

Comment: I don't know what else I can put to complete.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:
When I tried bottom 0 and right 0, there was some annoying bottom margin below the footer which would not go away.
I fixed it with top: 100% and position absolute:

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

footer{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #c10f3f, #010168);
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this styling;

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
header {
    position: absolute;
    float: top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8%;
    background-color: #424242;
    color: #FFD740;
}
.title-div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto 5%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    border-right: solid 2px #FFD740;
}

header nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    left: 15%;
}

header ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}

header ul  li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 2% auto 0; 
}
footer {
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #FFD740; 
    background-color: #424242;
}
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/qyydmnh2/)** is a demo

Answer (score 0):

the answer posted by @divy3993 works but sometimes making footer absolute keeps it stranded on the middle of the page. Atleast that's what had happened to me. So I made a small change, I'll post it below

```
#footer {
  background: #ffab62;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative; //make relative instead of absolute
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

css:

```css
#footer
{
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-color: #ffab62;
}
```

html:

```html
<doctype HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id = footer></div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap 4 and mdboostrap and I had the same problem.

the inline style worked for me:

```
<footer class="page-footer lighten-5" 
        style="position: relative; bottom:0; width: 100% !important;" >

....

</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap 3 and I found that a combination of methods was needed:

Here's the sample HTML with the CSS further below. Hope this helps!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>

<body class="site">
<header>
<!-- any content as header, like your nav menu -->
</header>

<main class="Site-content">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Put your page content here -->
</div>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
<!-- put your footer content here -->
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and the associated CSS to pin the footer at the bottom of the page regardless of whether the content fills the page or not.

```
<style>
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your first mistakes are just using absolute position on everything and min-height on many stuff you don't need.

For starter just remove all absolute stuff and put min-height only in div named "body" after that footer will be glued to the #body by default, after that your footer won't be flying around where ever it wants.

Best way to use absolute in divs is: 
 - when you already have existing div with relative position, and then you put another div with an absolute position inside of a div with a relative position.

Also, play only with pixel values if you start going with % you will get lost like you already did.

Answer (score -1):

```
position: fixed
```

Use this to set `position` to `Fixed`.

Comment: OP don't want position fixed.