# Ensure footer will stick to bottom of page and flex with content

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a footer right now that will stick to the bottom of the page but when it runs up to content it will sit over top of it. I obviously want it to be pushed down by whatever container content it comes next to.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I would like the bottom of that table to push it down. Here is my CSS and HTML

### BODY AND CONTAINER CSS

```
body {
  color: $base-text-color;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: $base-background-color;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 18px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

### FOOTER CSS

```
.footer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

### APPLICATION HTML

```
<body>
  <%= render 'shared/top_bar' %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= render 'shared/errors' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
</body>
```

I'm really stumped by this one and can't seem to find the answer! All help would be great thanks!

Comment: Ah. I commented previous your question, thinking that foorter is a child of container :)

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796085/how-to-stick-footer-to-bottom-not-fixed-even-with-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a sticky footer and not a fixed one. Fixed, the content will not push it. Sticky, it will remain at the bottom until it's pushed by content. Please beware that inserting a padding into the footer affects it's size and you have to adjust other measures for this to work correctly.
Please note that I added a padding of 20px to the .container so I had to increase 40px on the bottom margin and on the .push div.

I would also advise that you should use Footer element instead of a div .footer

Here is the code

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -80px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding:20px;
}
.push {
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.footer {
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  border: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
 <div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quia accusamus, aut consequuntur harum velit, cupiditate nisi quos soluta nihil tempore. Sint facere aliquid officia atque molestiae, nulla numquam excepturi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quia accusamus, aut consequuntur harum velit, cupiditate nisi quos soluta nihil tempore. Sint facere aliquid officia atque molestiae, nulla numquam excepturi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quia accusamus, aut consequuntur harum velit, cupiditate nisi quos soluta nihil tempore. Sint facere aliquid officia atque molestiae, nulla numquam excepturi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quia accusamus, aut consequuntur harum velit, cupiditate nisi quos soluta nihil tempore. Sint facere aliquid officia atque molestiae, nulla numquam excepturi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quia accusamus, aut consequuntur harum velit, cupiditate nisi quos soluta nihil tempore. Sint facere aliquid officia atque molestiae, nulla numquam excepturi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quia accusamus, aut consequuntur harum velit, cupiditate nisi quos soluta nihil tempore. Sint facere aliquid officia atque molestiae, nulla numquam  
  <div class="push"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/luisalves/pen/ggZWGv

Answer (score 1):

i have added css in your code from line 6

as your footer's height is fixed i have leveraged that fact

please read it and comment if you dont understand

```css
body {
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: green;
  /*magic is here */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh; 
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  /*magic ends here */
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 18px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.footer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  lorem*10
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae quia accusamus, aut consequuntur harum velit, cupiditate nisi quos soluta nihil tempore. Sint facere aliquid officia atque molestiae, nulla numquam excepturi.</div>
  <div class="footer">i am here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding different div for footer...
something like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        ..some code..
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <p align="center">Copyright &copy;</p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```